# New broker cannot join the cluster (Kafka)

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are currently configuring our kafka cluster to have SSL and ACL.

Our cluster is composed of 3 nodes, and all three of them contain the same SSL/TLS(because I just copied the certificates from one node to the other two nodes) and all other kafka configurations.

Two of the nodes are successful in joining the cluster, but the last one does not.

Here is the error:
[ReplicaFetcherThread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZWpH.png)

It says

> UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.

I find it weird because all three of them have the same configuration.
The three servers are in Amazon EC2. They also have the same security group.

Hope you can help me understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but am still to low to comment. But you say they all have the same configuration. Did you make sure to bump the broker id on the one that's failing?